# Why is a beracha levatala considered saying G-d's name in vain?

Tags: blessing, halacha-theory, bracha-levatala

If for example one was holding a piece of pineapple and with concentration made the bracha of HaEtz, with the intention to praise G-d for creating fruit, and then afterwards realizes that he made the wrong bracha, why is this considered saying G-d's name in vain and not as a praise (like a voluntary prayer)?

Comment: I remember that for most poskim it's derabanan. The problem is a lack of accuracy or of scrutiny

Comment: If it's a biblical prohibition, then it's from a drasha on a verse (brachot 33a) which you can't really ask questions on. It just is.

Comment: I would add that aside from the aspect of praise in a bracha, it also comes to accomplish a task. There is intent in the bracha to allow you to eat this pineapple. That intent is not accomplished and in fact is wrong, which shows an element of disrespect to G-D’s name.

Comment: Ritbaכל המברך ברכה שאינה צריכה עובר משום לא תשא וכו'. פי' מדרבנן קאמר ואסמכתא בעלמא הוא והכי משמע ממאי דאמרי' לעיל בפ' מי שמתו ספק אמר או"י ספק לא אמר חוזר ואומר אמת ויציב מ"ט אמת ויציב מדאורייתא ואי אמרת ברכה שאינה צריכה אסורה מדאורייתא הרי מכניס עצמו בספק איסורא דאורייתא ועדיף ליה דלא לימא כלל בספק לו שאינו אלא שב ואל תעשה מלעבור בספק לאו דאורייתא אלא ודאי מדרבנן הוא וטוב לו שיוציא עצמו מספק דאורייתא אף על פי שעובר בספק איסורא דרבנן: 

https://www.sefaria.org/Ritva_on_Berakhot.33a.15

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3338340/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-215-Responding-Amen-After-Blessings.htm#v3